# Play / Pause audio file with JavaScript / jquery by fetching .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

When play is pressed the file mp3 should play when clicked again the mp3 should pause. The goal is to fetch the file name from 'key' and add the directory + .mp3 in javascript / jquery after.

Its playing but not pausing.

```
<span class="play" key="cef83b993c716dd543b6fa4f053cc4a4">Play</span>
<script>
  $(".play").click(function(){
    var audio = new Audio("beats/" + $(this).attr('key') + ".mp3");
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
    }   
    else {
      audio.pause();
    }
    $( this ).toggleClass( "pause" ); // switch to some new css for a pause button
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is, everytime you click on it, it executes this:

```
var audio = new Audio("beats/" + $(this).attr('key') + ".mp3");
```

So what you need to do is, add a condition in the front:

```
var audio;
if (typeof audio == "undefined")
  audio = new Audio("beats/" + $(this).attr('key') + ".mp3");
```

Your full code would be:

```
<span class="play" key="cef83b993c716dd543b6fa4f053cc4a4">Play</span>
<script>
  var audio;
  $(".play").click(function(){
    if (typeof audio == "undefined")
      audio = new Audio("beats/" + $(this).attr('key') + ".mp3");
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
    }   
    else {
      audio.pause();
    }
    $( this ).toggleClass( "pause" ); // switch to some new css for a pause button
  });
</script>
```